# Multiple API Calls on Web Server

Tags: api, web-services, optimization, web-servers

I am trying to build a Tumblr Site that makes API calls to Social Network sites and return data and render on the Tumblr Site. And the thing is Tumblr doesn't allow PHP on their HTML Editor. So my decision was to create my own PHP API that calls the Social Networking APIs, then call my API via javascript on the Tumblr Site to get data. One of the reasons why I need to call the Social Networking APIs on PHP on my web server is because I need it to work with the backend CMS for administration.

My concern though is would it be too much for the web server that is hosting my API when it calls Multiple API requests to Twitter, Instagram, YouTube, etc. Since the site would have multiple users at the same time (say 500 users a day)? Is Web server load a concern for this approach? Would you recommend a better approach for this?

Comment: 'Load' is just one concern. 'Delay' is another because you put an extra layer in between.